# IntelliJ IDEA Angular's component import style error

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

When I try to add a component in the module's declarations, I have an auto-completion for it. After I add it, IntelliJ adds the following line:

```
import {UserComponent} from "./user/user.component";
```

So I have TSLint error for braces. The right import should be:

```
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
```

Where can I change the behavior of auto-completion or how do you deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with installing tslint plugin from JB's repository.

To change braces:

Go to preferences (cmd + ,) -> editor -> code style -> punctuation tab. Select single quotes from dropdown.

To change import spacing:

Go to preferences (cmd + ,) -> editor -> code style -> spaces tab
Mark checkbox "ES6 import/export braces" in "Within" section.

[image]